# Vue not rendering a simple Hello World

Tags: vue.js

I use Windows, here I included script for vue, I didn't install vue, just use script.
The title of page is visible, yet "Hello vue" is not shown.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Vue-basis</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        <div id="app">
            <h1>Hello Vue</h1>
        </div>      
    </script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script> 
    <script>
        new Vue({
            el: '#app'
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't put the div inside of a `script` tag. You want to attach your Vue model to an existing DOM structure, so you shouldn't define it as a template.

Comment: Yes, that helped! Thanks